# (Android Studio Java) Pushing elements up programmatically as other elements come in

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a simple prototype app that, on the click of a button, makes a new TextView, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnsSC.png. However, I would like for the app, instead of the bottom having 32 and the top having 560, for the bottom having 560 and the top having 32, like in a messaging app. Is there any way to do this programmatically?

Sorry for the bad English, not very fluent.

Code I am currently using:

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.send_message);
                String message = editText.getText().toString();
                editText.getText().clear();

                ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainConstraint);
                TextView view = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                Button send_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button);
                view.setId(View.generateViewId());
                ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
                layout.addView(view,0);
                set.clone(layout);
                set.constrainHeight(view.getId(), ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
                set.constrainWidth(view.getId(), ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
                set.connect(view.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, send_button.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP);
                set.connect(view.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, layout.getId(), ConstraintSet.END);
                set.setMargin(view.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, dpToPx(16, MainActivity.this));
                set.setMargin(view.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, dpToPx(i[0], MainActivity.this));
                view.setText("message with the id:" + i[0]);
                i[0] = i[0] + 48;
                view.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.sent_message_shape));
                set.applyTo(layout);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing this line

```
layout.addView(view,0);
```

to this

```
layout.addView(view);
```

because, the 0 parameter is the index, so you are always putting in the beginning

Comment: It doesn't look like this works. I tried it and I get a replica of what happened before.